# Why is this regex behaving like this?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression [here](http://rubular.com/regexes/13484), and I want it to return *only* users, comments, and posts. However, even though I have `\s`, whitespace, in my negative character set, it still is extracting a match from it. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems did not match any space character, but just a position, since * will match a string with length 0.
Try `([^\s().,]+)`

Answer (score 1):

It's matching empty positions (zero-length strings), not spaces, and that's because you're using the star (zero or more) rather than the plus (one or more) repetition modifier. `([^.,()\s]+)` returns only "users", "comments" and "posts".

Answer (score 1):

yes its because of the +
Here is a powered regexp that extract each parameter 
$1 = user
$2 = comment
$3 = post

(([^.,()\s]+).(([^.,()\s]+), ([^.,()\s]+)))

but of course, cant exists comments or posts with those reserverd characters

or this its  a more flexible example
(([^.,()\s]+).(\s*([^.,()\s]+)\s*,\s*([^.,()\s]+)\s*))